# Putting PreferenceScreen within RelativeLayout in preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to put Layout and Button Element in res/xml/preferences.xml. But it is throwing an error saying that it can't find the class for RelativeLayout and Button. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/title_notifications">

            <SwitchPreference
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="@string/notification_A"
                android:title="A" />

            <SwitchPreference
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="@string/notification_B"
                android:title="B" />

            <SwitchPreference
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="@string/notification_C"
                android:title="C" />

        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:onClick="showMPowerWebsite"
        android:id="@+id/button_abc_website"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="Arial"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is error Text.

```
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.RelativeLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 26 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout` and `Button` are **not** even supposed to be in your XML file for preferences. You should probably create a custom preference activity instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can't do that. From [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html):

> Because your app's settings UI is built using Preference objects instead of View objects, you need to use a specialized Activity or Fragment subclass to display the list settings:

So that would be why you can't use the button, and your second error would be using a relativelayout as the base layout, again from the docs:

> The root node for the XML file must be a PreferenceScreen element.

So if you just removed the button and the RelativeLayout this should work.

You could also extend the preference class and create your own which would allow you to use regular views like this, but that is more complicated and you should only do it if you can't build the screen you would like with the provided preference structure in place.